# How to apply code of ionic into cordova source code

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have **completed my app into cordova** now what i want is to **set the code of Ionic** with its all functionality

I have created **multi page application** now i want to **set it into template directory** of ionic and run all from index file

But don't know **how to access my ajax-javascript api** from it.

Any help or flow ?